# Linux server: Would a cache scheme help reduce hits to 3rd-party server?

Tags: php, linux, caching

I have a situation where my Linux server will be running a website which gets some of its data from a 3rd-party server through a SOAP interface. The data isn't exactly real-time, but it does change every 5 minutes or so. I was told not to have our website hammer their website for data, which I can completely understand.

So I wondered if this was a good candiate to use a cache scheme of some type. Where when a user comes to our web page to display the data, if it's less than 5 minutes old (for example), it would get that data from our server instead of polling the 3rd-party for it. This way, if 100 users at once come to our website, our server won't be access the 3rd-party website 100 times to share the same exact data within a given time-frame.

Is this a practical thing to do in PHP? Or should this be written in a faster language when it comes to caching? Are their cache packages for this sort of situation which can be used along with a PHP Joomla application? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think [memcached](http://memcached.org/) is a good choice.

You can set timeout when you store content to memcached server, if key-value missed, retrieve data from 3rd-part server and store again.

There is memcached extension for PHP, check [doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) here.

Comment: I would also mention not to bother with a faster language -- unless you are unhappy with the speed *after* adding a layer of caching.

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of ways to solve the problem -we can't say which is the *right* one without knowing a lot more about the constraints you are working in or how the service is used. If you are using Joomla then you're obviously not bothered about performance - it would be really hard to write anything which has a measurable impact on your html generation times. This does not need to "be written in a faster language", but....

1. can you install additional software?
2. have you got access to cron?
3. at what rate is the service consumed?
4. how many webservers do you have consuming the service - do they have a shared filesystem? Are they on the same sub-net?
5. Is the SOAP response cacheable?
6. how do you deal with non-availability of the service?

For a very scalable solution I would suggest running a simple forward proxy (e.g. squid) but do make sure that it's not accessible from the internet. Sven (see comment elsewhere) is right about POST *sometimes* not being cacheable - but you can cache the response from a surrogate script on your own site accessed via GET returning appropriate caching instructions - and this could return the data as a serialized php array / object which is much less expensive to process. Indeed whichever method you choose I would recommend caching the parsed response - not the XML. This also allows you to override poor caching information from the service.

If the rate is less than around 1 per minute then the cron solution is overkill. But if its more than 20 per minute then it makes a lot of sense. If you don't have access to cron / can't install your own software then you might consider simply caching the response and refreshing the cache on demand. Don't bother with memcache unless you are already using it. APC is faster on a single server - but memcache is distributed. If you have multiple servers then use whatever cluster storage you are currently sharing your data in (distributed filesystem / database cluster / shared filesystem....).

Don't try to use locking / mutexes around the cache refresh unless you really have to (i.e. only if accessing the service more than once every 5 minutes is a mortal sin)  - this gets real complicated real quick - it's too easy to introduce bugs.

Do make sure you buffer and validate any responses before writing them to the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use HTTP. Most of the heavy lifting has already been built into your web server.

Since SOAP is just a simple HTTP POST request with an XML body, you could set up your website or HTTP API in front of the SOAP endpoint to act like a translator to regular HTTP, attaching the appropriate HTTP caching headers on the transformed response body and then configure an NGinx reverse proxy in front of it.

Notably: if the transformation is simple you could just use XSLT to transform the response body from the SOAP API and remove the web service layer entirely.

Comment: I think it is way easier to NOT expose the third party SOAP service through a specially configured proxy to the entire world. Additionally, POST requests usually are not cached unless the server explicitly allows it - SOAP responses are non-cacheable on the HTTP level.

Comment: Ignoring the implications of what the proxy will and won't do, this sounds like an incredibly complex solution to a simple problem. Neither header-rewriting reverse proxies nor XSLT are exactly simple technologies to learn compared to a few PHP classes to check if a local cache is stale.

Comment: @Sven: since when are SOAP POSTs not cacheable? From RFC 2616: "Responses to this method are not cacheable, unless the response includes appropriate Cache-Control or Expires header fields. However, the 303 (See Other) response can be used to direct the user agent to retrieve a cacheable resource." See also http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Frdyn_webservicescaching.html

Comment: @Sven It's way easier to build an entire web application and a cron job to re-implement HTTP caching? The OP has already indicated that the result of the SOAP call is not explicitly cacheable. Why not expose that knowledge to the reverse proxy as caching headers and allow the reverse proxy to do what it was built to?

Comment: @IMSoP I fail to see how this is "incredibly complex". The OP requires a way to translate a SOAP request into a response cached according to  some basic rules. This is precisely what HTTP excels at. If basic XSLT and basic web server configuration is too complicated to implement, what makes you think doing it in PHP will make it any easier? Why re-implement it with an entire web application stack when HTTP already adequately provides a solution?

Comment: Seriously, this is definitely the way to go. XSLT is extremely easy and nginx+XSLT would be perfect for the job. It's also considerably faster than anything you could whip up in PHP, especially if you think setting up nginx+XSLT is too complicated. On a related note, this sounds exactly like what I did here: http://ef.gy/using-nginx-as-a-proxy-server and here, with s/Twitter/Your Upstream SOAP Service/g: http://ef.gy/embedding-tweets-on-websites-with-xslt - the whole blog is just nginx+XSLT, by the way, check the source code to see how easy that really is.

Comment: Consider for a moment that "some data from a third party" is just the stock market quote of some company, and the rest of the website already exists. Do you think it is a viable solution to transform the whole existing website into something that gets also added to the XSLT transformation in addition to that stock price? Who would maintain that? Knowledge in PHP seems to be there, XSLT - not so much.

Comment: Interesting discussion. One point worth noting is that SOAP is designed to be an RPC mechanism, which happens to use HTTP as a transport. It's therefore likely that some application logic is required to interact with the service anyway, as the API will not have been designed with "passive" processing in mind. Adding caching to an existing application layer, at the level of processed data rather than individual calls, would then be both simpler and more efficient than adding an extra layer of pre-processing and introducing additional dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a very small one, which does not require a complicated solution.

You could write a small cron job that is executed every five minutes, sends the request to the SOAP server, and stores the result in a local file. If any script needs the data, it reads the local file. This will result in 288 requests to the SOAP server per day, and have excellent performance for any script call that needs the results because they are already on your server.

If you do not have cron jobs available and cannot fake them, any other cache will do. You really don't need fancy stuff like Memcached, unless it already is available. Storing the result to a cache file will work as well. Note that if you have to really fetch the SOAP result from the origin, this will take some more time and might affect the perceived performance of your site.

There are plenty of frameworks which also offer cache support, and if you use one you should investigate if there is support included. I'm not sure if Joomla has something appropriate for you. Otherwise, you can implement something yourself. It isn't that hard.

Comment: I'm bemused by the implication that memcached would be overkill but a cron job to pre-cache the data, rather than reactively caching it when it expires, would be reasonable.

Comment: A filesystem is usually already available - Memcached usually is not. Whether or not cron jobs can be used depends on the type of hosting used.

Comment: I was thinking more that for the majority of caching requirements, pre-caching is not only unnecessary, but possibly actively undesirable, so it seemed an odd place to start. If the website has no visitors overnight, why hammer the 3rd-party with one or more requests (we don't know how many variant calls there might be) every 5 minutes when you're going to throw the data away?

Comment: You might be right, but there is no info whether "the data" changes based on a parameter or not. If not, prefetching is completely ok. It does not matter if five minutes ago there was NO request that filled the cache.

Comment: Sure, it's a useful additional thought, and I added it to my answer; I just don't think pre-caching is the first thing to consider, given inline caching is a lot easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Cache functionality comes in various flavours:

- memory-based, where a separate process on the server holds data in RAM (or overflows to disk) and you query it like you would a database; very efficient and powerful, and will have options to manage storage use and clear up after themselves, but requires setting up additional software on the server; e.g. [memcached](http://memcached.org/), [redis](http://redis.io/)
- file-based, where you just write the data to disk; less efficient, but can be implemented in "user-land" code, i.e. pure PHP; beware of filling up your disk with variant caches that have expired but not been cleaned up; many frameworks have an implementation of this built in
- database-backed, where you push data into an RDBMS (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL) or fully-featured NoSQL store (e.g. MongoDB); might make sense if you have a large amount of data, and can trade a bit of performance; as with files, you need to make sure that stale data is cleaned up

In each case, the basic idea is that you create a "key" that can tell one request from another (e.g. the name of the SOAP call and its input parameters, serialized), and pick a "lifetime" (how long you want to carry on using the same copy of the data). The caching engine or library then checks for a cache with that key, and if it is still within its "lifetime" returns the previously cached data. If there is a "cache miss" (there is no cache for that key, or it has expired), you perform the costly operation (in your case, the SOAP call) and save to the cache, using the same key.

You can do more complex things, like pre-caching things in the background so that there is never a cache miss, or having some code paths which accept stale data in order to return quickly, but these can generally be implemented on top of whatever you're using as the main caching solution.

**Edit** Another important decision is at what level of granularity to cache the data, in relation to processing it. At one extreme, you could cache each individual SOAP call: simple to set up, but means re-processing the same data repeatedly, and can cause problems if two responses are related, but cached independently and may get out of sync. At the other extreme, you can cache whole rendered pages: pages load very fast once cached, but creating variations based on the same data without repeating work becomes tricky. In between are various points in your code where you have processed and combined data into meaningful chunks: if your application is well-written, these are the input and output of major functions, or possibly even complete model objects; this is more work to implement, as you have to choose the right keys (avoiding two contexts overwriting each other's caches while ignoring variables that have no impact on the data in question) and values (avoiding repeats of costly work without having to store huge blobs of data which will be slow to unserialize and use up the capacity of your cache store). As with anything else, no approach suits all needs, and a complex application will probably involve caching at multiple levels for different purposes.